# possible to initialize a PHP array with keys only?

Tags: php, arrays, initialization

I'm just looking for a MORE eloquent way of defining an array of empty error strings for a mail form then this...

```
 $err = array('NAME'=>'', 'EMAIL'=>'', 'ADDR'=>'', 'CS_LOC'=>'', 'ZIP'=>'','PHONE'=>'', 'COMMENTS'=>'', 'FILE'=> '');
```

Since I have to flush these occasionally anyway, certainly anytime the form posts, I've already set up a function like the below which I call as needed, like this.

```
    function clearFormErrors(&$ary) { // fill error array with empty strings
   $keys = array_keys($ary);
   $filled = array_fill_keys($keys, '');
   }
```

Not a big deal **[EDIT]:, but since I'm going to call this anyway, it would be nice if there were some nice 'wishlist' way I could just define the array **KEYS** when I declare it**, like this...

```
$err = array('NAME', 'EMAIL, 'ADDR', 'CS_LOC, 'ZIP,'PHONE', 'COMMENTS, 'FILE');
```

Of course the above does NOT have that desired effect. **I'm just curious if there is some simple directive or method that I've missed in the PHP docs that would just let me define the keys (with or without some default type)**. I'm sure there is a more complicated function that could be created to build a new array using the keys (now values) from my above 'wishlist' array, but it sounds like it wouldn't make the code any shorter or more 'eloquent', right?

Comment: Probably you should use your own array implementation (ArrayAccess interface: http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php)

Comment: Thanks... I'll study it to see what I can learn there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have array of keys, [array_fill_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) is the most elegant way to "reset" the array. The other way that makes sense is [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), but for your simple task it seems like a little overhead.

Comment: I thought I could only use array_fill_keys if the "keys" were numeric? In this case my keys are descriptive text strings. Now if PHP gave me something like C/C++ or Java enums, then the keys could indeed be numeric, and the lookup references would not have to be strings, and it would probably run faster. But that's a LOT of "ifs".

Comment: You can only use `array_fill` if the keys are numeric. `array_fill_keys` works for any type of keys. In this case (and many other cases), I'd sacrifice milliseconds for elegant code. Performance of such tasks doesn't matter that much.

Comment: Yes, thats what I thought, and so that's what I'm using in my clearFormErrors() for repetitive clearing. But again what I was hoping for was a more eloquent way of creating the array to begin with. Meaning, initially create the array with its named keys, without bothering to include all those empty string constructs.

Comment: I think it's eloquent to use `array_fill_keys`, because empty string is not like default way to start an array or anything. Why not false/null/0?

Comment: I *DO* appreciate your help, but if you look at the function I created you'll see array_fill_keys() is exactly what I originally said I was doing anytime I need to clear my error strings. But my question is about a better way to declare the original array.  I don't think you are understanding my original question, and I'm not sure how to explain it better at this point.

Comment: I think I understand your question. What I'm telling you is that `array_fill_keys` is elegant enough to use it the way you do. Array with empty strings is nothing common enough to make separate language construction to create it. What is that you don't like about `$err = array_fill_keys(['NAME', 'EMAIL', 'ADDR'], '');` ?

Comment: AH!!! well thanks again. Now I understand, and that both looks much better AND works great.  I've edited my original question in an attempt to clarify, but I didn't understand what you were trying to tell me, which was to use array_fill_keys() during actual declaration. I was not aware I could do what your last example suggests, so when you spoke of it I was still envisioning it called separately from the original declaration. I'm still not sure I understand how it works, since array_fill_keys() is acting on an array that doesn't exist yet, but it does work.

Comment: `array_fill_keys` just RETURNS a value, which happens to be an array. I think you don't understand yet what returning a value is.