# New Array's key should be another Array's value

Tags: php, arrays, key

I want to create new array.
Value of element in array should be blank.
Key of array should another array's value.

```
$Oldarr =  Array
(
    [0] => Webseite,
    [1] => Bestellung,
    [2] => Verkäufer,
    [3] => Käufer,
    [4] => Warenwert,
    [5] => Lieferkosten,
    [6] => Produktname,
    [7] => Article Nr,
    [8] => Anzahl
);
```

And New array shoud be

```
$Newarr =  Array
(
    ['Bestellung'] => '',
    ['Verkäufer'] => '',
    ['Käufer'] => '',
    ['Warenwert'] => '',
    ['Lieferkosten'] => '',
    ['Produktname'] => '',
    ['Article Nr'] => '',
    ['Anzahl'] => ''
);
```

Comment: i post answer with null values

Comment: [possible to initialize a PHP array with keys only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31793758/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use array_flip to make key as values and values as keys.

```
$newarr = array_flip($Oldarr);
```

If you need to set blank values as well then you can use array_fill_keys like:

```
$newarr = array_flip($Oldarr);
$newarr = array_fill_keys($newarr, null);//for null values
$newarr = array_fill_keys($newarr, '');//for empty string values
```

**Edited**:

only **array_fill_keys** will work in your scenario (credit goes to @Sougata Bose who commented here)

```
$newarr = array_fill_keys($Oldarr, '');//for empty string values
```

Comment: With blank values.

Comment: array flip will be needed

Comment: If an associative array is used as the second parameter of array_fill_keys, then the associative array will be appended in all the values of the first array. according to example in docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php

Comment: Works well with provided array.

Comment: Yes checked it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code:

```
$new = array_flip($Oldarr);
$new = array_fill_keys($Oldarr,'');
```